# Copy the schema of a SQL Azure data warehouse?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I want to copy our data warehouse's tables, procs, users, etc. to a new staging DW, but I don't need any of the data.

I've tried creating a snapshot with Redgate SQL Compare and get an error saying DW snapshots aren't supported. I've also tried scripting the DW, but I get an error saying "The 'DwTableDistribution' property is not supported on SqlDatabase edition database of SqlAzureDatabase SQL Server with version 13.0.0".

The only idea I have left is just to restore a full copy of the prod DW and wipe out the data, but that seems like a pretty huge undertaking when all I need is the skeleton of the DW. Any ideas?

Comment: though question sounds little confusing, but i reached to solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few options:

- newer versions of SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) have support for scripting Azure SQL Data Warehouse now known as Azure Synapse Analytics.  Right-click the database in Object Explorer and explore the scripting options, making sure you set the version for Azure SQL Data Warehouse
- mssql-scripter - a command line scripting tool which supports SQL DW.  See [here](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-scripter).
- Visual Studio 2019 database projects - try importing the database schema into a Data Project which now supports SQL DW.

Comment: Ah, I feel like such a dummy for not realizing the option in your first point existed! It seems to have worked perfectly, thank you! If anyone's interested, in the Generate and Publish Scripts window, on the Set Scripting Options tab, I clicked the Advanced button and change the "Script for the database engine edition" setting to "Microsoft Azure SQL Data Warehouse Edition". Worked like a charm!